# MySQL query joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables: projects, lists, items.

The project joins to the lists on `project_id`, and the items join to the lists on `list_id`, and the goal is to have all of the row data for each.

**What have I tried?**
Well, I actually have only been able to do it by having three separate queries / outputs and then just iterating through them with PHP to combine data.

Is it possible to write the query so that way I end up with one data object that I can easily iterate through?

```
project (w details)
-- list (and its details)
----- item (w details)
----- item (w details)
----- item (w details)
-- list (w details)
----- item (w details)
----- item (w details)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
select
    a.project_id,
    b.list_id,
    c.item_id
from
    projects a
        join lists b
            on a.project_id=b.project_id
        join items c
            on b.list_id=c.list_id
```

Output will be something like:

```
project_id | list_id | item_id
 1         | 5       |  45
 1         | 5       |  46
 1         | 8       |  12
```

Or did you want to return all the parts of it in a single row?

If you want a single row, you can do something along the lines of:

```
select
    a.project_id,
    group_concat(b.list_id) as listIDs,
    group_concat(c.item_id) as itemIDs
from
    projects a
        join lists b
            on a.project_id=b.project_id
        join items c
            on b.list_id=c.list_id
```

But it will get messier in PHP to deal with all the grouped stuff.

Output will be something like:

```
project_id | list_id | item_id
 1         | 5,8     |  45, 46, 12
```

You could also mix and match the two to maybe get the best of both worlds:

```
select
    a.project_id,
    b.list_id as listIDs,
    group_concat(c.item_id) as itemIDs
from
    projects a
        join lists b
            on a.project_id=b.project_id
        join items c
            on b.list_id=c.list_id
```

Output will be something like:

```
project_id | list_id | item_id
 1         | 5       |  45, 46
 1         | 8       |  12
```

Comment: well, yes I think so. I want to be able to send all of this data to the view.

Comment: @Kristian No, you will have LESS redundant data in a single row, but you will have to do more trickery in PHP to split them all out again. I was thinking of things like `group_concat()` and the like to bring all the items together for example.

Comment: thanks dude. Ok so I just updated my question, I realized after getting two responses that I should have said that I want the whole row for each of those. BUT i think thats not possible when the rows aren't really matching keynames, right?

Comment: @Kristian Added a mixed one for you as well, less redundant data, things grouped nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: If you want to display the way you projected

```
select
    a.project_id,
    b.list_id,
    c.item_id
from
    projects a
    left join lists b  on a.project_id=b.project_id
    left join items c  on b.list_id=c.list_id
    order by b,c
```