# MySQL dynamic table name relation

Tags: php, mysql, relationship, relation

I have 3 MySQL tables: cars, users and visitors.

Table cars can be related to table users or table visitors. Tables users and visitors have different table structures. I would like to join all these tables and retrieve person data. Currently I'm using PHP to retrieve person data.

Is this the best table structure for creating these kind of relationships and is there a way to retrieve person information using a single MySQL query?

```
 [cars]
id | car_name | person_type | person_id
--------------+-------------+--------
1  | car 1    | user        | 1
2  | car 2    | visitor     | 1

 [users]
id | name
---+----------
1  | person 1

 [visitors]
id | first_name | last_name
---+------------+----------
1  | person     | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an outer join like this:

```
select
    a.ID,
    a.car_name,
    a.person_type,
    b.name as username,
    c.name as visotorName
from
    cars a
        left outer join users b
            on a.person_id=b.ID
        left outer join visitors c
            on a.person_id=c.ID
```

I wrote a rather [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806556/mysql-query-joining-three-tables/11806579#11806579) on a very similar question you might want to have a quick read of as well. It shows some other functions you can use to nicely format the data in the way you want in terms of number of rows returned - and what is returned per row.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available. One is mentioned in the post. A select would be like this:

```
select * from
   cars a
   left join users u on (a.person_type='user' and a.person_id=u.id)
   left join visitors v on (a.person_type='visitor' and a.person_id=v.id)
```

Another option is instead of `person_type` and `person_id` simply have both `user_id` and `visitor_id`. Both are nullable, and you can even put a strong foreign keys on them. The select is quite similar:

```
select * from
   cars a
   left join users u on (a.user_id=u.id)
   left join visitors v on (a.visitor_id=v.id)
```

Last but not least, perhaps you can merge the `users` and `visitors` table into a single table?

```
[cars]
  ID | car_name |  person_id
-----+----------+-------------
   1 | car 1    | 1
   2 | car 2    | 2

[persons]
  ID | type    | name
-----+---------+----------
   1 | user    | person 1
   2 | visitor | person 2
```

The select then becomes super simple:

```
select * from cars c join persons p on (c.person_id=p.id)
```